# Why aren't these two sql statements returning same output?

Tags: sql, join, cartesian-product

I'm just getting started with sql and have the objective to transform this:

```
select X.persnr 
from Pruefung X 
where X.persnr in (
    select Y.persnr 
    from pruefung Y 
    where X.matrikelnr <> Y.matrikelnr)
```

output:

[image]

into the same output but using a form of join. I tried it the way below but I can't seem to get "rid" of the cartesian product as far as i can see. Or maybe i misunderstood the above statement what it should actually do. For me the above says "for each unique matrikelnr display all corresponding persnr".

```
select X.persnr 
from Pruefung X 
join pruefung y on x.persnr=y.persnr 
where x.matrikelnr<>y.matrikelnr
```

output: A long list (I don't want to fill the entire question with it) - i am guessing the cartesian product from the join

This is the relation I am using.

[image: Relation I am using]

Edit: Distinct (unless i am using it in the wrong place) won't work because then persnr is only displayed once, thats not the objective though.

Comment: the first query actually does : select from Pruefung where the same persnr exists for a a diferent matrikelnr.
What do you want your join to do ?

Comment: my objective is - if possible -  to achieve the exact same result with a  join - for practise purposes. But I've been playing around with it for some time and can't do it

Comment: It returns this because that is how SQL works. Please say what you expect & why at the first subexpression with unexpected result or we can't address your misconceptions & you are just asking for yet another presentation of SQL without us knowing what would help you better than any other one. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table.

Comment: hm alright I'll try that next time. I thought i had explained what i wanted and what I've tried. Regarding text not images - thanks. 
Regarding mentioning the DBMS and DDL will try and do that. I was using an online DBS from our uni so i wouldn't even know what to write as an DBMS . Thanks for your advise though.

Comment: See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment. (I just happended to pass by again & saw your last comment.) See [ask] & other [help] links. Google site:meta.stackoverflow.com re sqlfiddle.com & db-fiddle.com. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) PS Please apply my comments to this question, it is here forever & the point of the site is to be a repository of (only) good questions.

Comment: @philipxy will update the question (hopefully) in the next couple of days when i have time 

Thanks for sharing and thanks for caring! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial query actually does:
select persnr from Pruefung if the same persnr exists for a a diferent matrikelnr.

"for each unique matrikelnr display all corresponding persnr"
This is achieved using aggregation:

Depending on the DBMS you are using you could use something like (SQL Server uses STRING_AGG, but MySQL uses GROUP_CONCAT)

```
SELECT matrikelnr,STRING_AGG(matrikelnr,',')
GROUP BY matrikelnr
```

You cannot easily achieve what you got from a correlated query (your first attempt) by using a join.

Edit:
A join does not result in a "Cartesian product" expect from when there is no join condition (CROSS JOIN). 
A join matches two sets based on a join condition. The reason why you get more entries is that the join looks at the join key (PERSNR) and does its matching.

For example for 101 you have 3 entries. That means you will get 3x3 reults.
You then filter out the results for the cases where X.matrikelnr <> Y.matrikelnr If we assume matrikelnr  is unique that would mean the row matched with itself. so you will lose 3 results ending up with 3x3 - 3 = 6.

If you want to achieve something in SQL you must first define what you are expecting to use and then use the appropiate tools (in this case correlated queries not joins)

Comment: alrighty, thank you! 
So there would be no way to "surpress" the cartesian product of a join?

Comment: ok i think i understand it better now. Thank you for your detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can write your 1st query with `EXISTS` instead of `IN` like:

```
select X.persnr 
from Pruefung X 
where exists (
    select 1 
    from pruefung Y 
    where X.persnr = Y.persnr and X.matrikelnr <> Y.matrikelnr
)
```

This way it's obvious that this query means:

> return all the `persnr`s of the table for which there exists another
>   row with the same `persnr` but different `matrikelnr`

For your sample data the result is all the `persnr`s of the table.

Your 2nd query though, does something different.
It **links** every row of the table with all the rows of the same table with the same `persnr` but different `matrikelnr`.
So for every row of the table you will get as many as rows as there are for the same `persnr`s but different `matrikelnr`s.
For example for the 1st row with `persnr = 101` and `matrikelnr = 8532478` you will get 2 rows because there are 2 rows in the table with `persnr = 101` and `matrikelnr <> 8532478`.

Comment: I think i forgot to mention -sorry about that -  it is a problem given to me as an assignment but i've spent too much time thinking about it so i decided to come here..

The "IN" sadly has to stay - its the instruction and we need to come up with a way of transforming it into a join..but @Gabrial Durac already said, it's not easily achievable, so i might wait and see what out teacher says..

Comment: I only used EXISTS to make it clearer what the 1st query does and how it is different from the 2nd query. You can't have a query that is equivalent to the 1st query with a self join.

Comment: ah, right. I understand - thank you! It does make it more clear!
Alrighty, then I'll wait and see what happens. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are right. It's the cartesian product's fault. Suppose you have persnr 1,1,1,2,2,2 in the first table and persnr 1,1,1,2,2 in the second. How many lines are you expecting to be returned?
In pdeuso-code it would go like this

```
Select 
...
WHERE persnr in (second table) 
-- 6 lines

Select persnr
FROM ...
JOIN ... ON a.persnr = b.persnr
-- 3X3 + 3X2 = 15 lines.

SELECT DISTINCT persnr
FROM ...
JOIN ... ON a.persnr = b.persnr
-- 2 lines (1 and 2)
```

Take your pick